# How to remove parameters from the root URL if it does I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

**Outdated (at least for Google)**

Recently I studied SEO a bit and found out that search engines somehow "don't like" parameters in the URL. Comprehensible since they aren't really human readable or tend to not be permanent.

---

The problem now is, what if I followed the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to set up I18n and then want to link to the `root_path`. It links to the root but adds a `?locale=en` to the URL. So `http://www.example.com/?locale=de`.

Even if SEO isn't affected about this anymore, I think it looks much nicer if the URL looks like `http://www.example.com/en` instead of `http://www.example.com/?locale=en`.

Comment: I want to point out that your premise is not correct for Google search. Google is indifferent to parameters in the URL and will index those pages like any other page: :https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080551?hl=en&ref_topic=6080547. And more here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en What Google will penalize you for is urls like foo.com/this-is-the-best-blog-post-about-cat-photos-that-you-have-ever-seen. I can't speak for Bing, maybe it does penalize.

Comment: Hi @ValAsensio! Thank you for this information! Obviously the docs I read were a bit older. However I think the URL looks still nicer without parameters :). I will adapt the question.

Comment: I agree with you that non-paramterized urls are preferable from an aesthetic standpoint, but it's good to know that Google will crawl either type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty straightforward solution.

I just added another route to my `routes.rb` called `i18n_root`.

**Example:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'

  # ...

  get ':locale' => 'welcome#index', as: :i18n_root
end
```

Now I just have to add the `i18n_root_path` to the links which link to the root path and everything works fine.

**The returned URL:**

```
http://www.example.com/en
```

Another possible solution, if I would have a lot of links already in the app, is to create a custom root.

**Example:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # root 'welcome#index'  <= We don't want to have a default root

  # ...

  get ':locale' => 'welcome#index', as: :root
end
```

Hope this helps other people as well.