# Rails SEO friendly URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got long brake from RoR and have some problem:

I have this URL:

```
http://www.xxx.zz/blog_posts/misieq?tit=some-fraze-in-here
```

How can I change "?" for params on "/" ?

This URL is created by:

```
<%= link_to f.title, blog_post_path( :tit => f.slug ) %></div>
```

Or how can I make most SEO friendly URL - I already use friendly_id gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a route to your `routes.rb` file which includes the `tit` paramter directly in the path.

For example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'post/:tit' => 'posts#show', as: :blog_post
end
```

Of course you have to adjust the routes to your needs.

Just have a short look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315715/how-to-remove-parameters-from-the-root-url-if-it-does-i18n). It doesn't matter if you have parameters in the URL anymore.

Comment: it doesn't change anything